Powershell: Resize one cell in Excel sheet
I write the script and the part of it answer for writing received data to the excel file in xlsx.
I need to change size for some special cells in sheet and can't find how to do it.
I need a help!
$ExcelObj = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$ExcelObj.visible=$true

#Open excel file
$ExcelWorkBook = $ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyOwn\Scritps\ResultAllertButton.xlsx")

#Copy last sheet, rename it and change position.

$SelectedSourceList = $ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(3)
$SelectedSourceList.Copy($SelectedSourceList)
$ExcelActiveSheet = $ExcelWorkBook.ActiveSheet.Index
$SelectedSourceList = $ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets.Item($ExcelActiveSheet)
$SelectedSourceList.Name = "$date"
for ($i=0; $i -le ($ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets.Count -1); $i++){
    $lastsheet = $ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets($ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets.Count)
    $SelectedSourceList.Move([System.Reflection.Missing]::Value, $lastsheet)
}

#Add values in the cells
$ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(4)
$SelectedSourceList.Cells.Item(1, 1) = 'blablabla1'
$SelectedSourceList.Cells.Item(2, 1) = "blablabla2: $date"
$SelectedSourceList.Cells.Item(3, 1) = "blablabla3: $Responsible"
if($result.DiferenceUsers.Count -ne $null) {
   foreach($obj in ($result.DiferenceUsers.Count -1)){
        $SelectedSourceList.Cells.Item(27, 6) = $result.DiferenceUsers[4]
   }
}


Can you give more details about what “size” you’re trying to change? Column width? Data length? Formatted table range? Or something else? This is a rare case where “current” and “desired” screenshots might be useful to illustrate the requirement…

I think, i mean a "data lengh" , if we both talk about one :)

I'm still a bit confused about your existing code - neither of your for / foreach loops are using the iteration variable - you're just repeating the same static command(s) each time it loops. Do you even need the loop constructs? Also, can you show a concrete example of what the data "size" is current (.e.g. what is an existing value?) and what you'd like it to be?

Yes, iteration cycles are needed:

The For loop copies a workbook sheet and puts it at the end of the list of sheets.
Foreach - writes the value of each array element from the hash table to the selected cell.

And here I have 2 problems. 1. The cell does not stretch in length, but only in height, while the value that should be written in one row into the cells is written as a column in this cell.
2. The value of each element of the array is overwritten in the cell, and not added with the next line.

We helped with solving one problem: You cannot increase the length of the cell, only the entire column is possible.
But I still can't write the values of all the array elements from the hash table into one cell.

@CatcherRem Your code is fundamentally wrong, looks that you need something like this: $DiferenceUsers = ''  ;  foreach($obj in ($result.DiferenceUsers)){        $DiferenceUsers += "`n" + $obj.DiferenceUsers[4]     } $SelectedSourceList.Cells.Item(27, 6) = $DiferenceUsers also the for loop looks useless, simply run $lastsheet = $ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets($ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets.Count)     $SelectedSourceList.Move([System.Reflection.Missing]::Value, $lastsheet) without a loop. To make one cell bigger you can merge cells.

Oh! Thank you!!! That's what I needed!
